# How do I scrape text characters from a string based on position using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to scrape certain characters from the html title - specifically the score (which is dynamic). In this case '9.1'.

What Jquery function should I use for this?

```
<div class="average_score" style="background-position:-9020.0px 0; background
-image: url('//cdn.images.reevoo.com/en-GB/scores/standard/transparent/110/
sprite.png');" title="Score is 9.1 out of 10 from 154 reviews"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var title = ($(".average_score").attr("title")).split(' ');
  console.log(title[2]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="average_score" style="background-position:-9020.0px 0; background
-image: url('//cdn.images.reevoo.com/en-GB/scores/standard/transparent/110/
sprite.png');" title="Score is 9.1 out of 10 from 154 reviews"></div>
```